# Latex table of content gives wrong page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I think it does not count the images. What should I do?

Comment: provide a minimal latex example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: run latex again (it can take more than run to stabilize) If it doesn't work, edit your question to have a _complete_ small document that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, we have run it many many times.

Comment: @pluton, it uses a gigantic template thus when something is removed  everything breaks.

Comment: @ilhan well clearly the default behaviour is to put the correct numbers in the table of content, so you need to give at least some clues abut your document.

Comment: Some information is required here. Though not knowing anything and assuming your document is well-typed, i would recommand to look for functions you used, that reset the pages counter.

Answer (score 6):

Analyze, where the entry for the table of contents is made. Page breaks can occur at different places than expected at the first glance, examples:

### Example: Page number too small

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{foo}
\chapter*{foo}
```

Then `\addcontentsline` can go to the previous or even the page before, then `\cleardoublepage` of `\chapter` starts a new page (or with an additional empty page).

An explicit page break makes sure, that `\addcontentsline` goes to the top of the page:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{foo}
\chapter*{foo}
```

### Example: Page number too large

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
```

Then the entry is set *after* the table of contents. If the table of contents is longer than one page, the page number will be too large.

Moving `\addcontentsline` in front of `\tableofcontents` solves this, see also the previous example that explains the explicit `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents
```

I hope you get an idea, how you can analyze your complex document to find the cause of the wrong page numbers.